# How to implement a db listener in Java

Tags: java, database, listener

I have a requirement where if a record is inserted in a db table , then automatically a java process needs to be executed.What is the easiest way to implement a db listener ?

Comment: Do you mean database trigger?..

Comment: Related, but not quite duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594955/how-to-make-a-database-listener-with-java

Answer (score 47):

I have a solution for Oracle. You don't need to create your own since now that Oracle bought Java it released a listener for it. As far as I know this does not use polling internally, instead notifications are pushed to the Java side (probably based on some trigger):

```
public interface oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeListener 
extends java.util.EventListener {
    void onDatabaseChangeNotification(oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeEvent arg0);
}
```

And you can implement it like this (this is just a sample):

```
public class DBListener implements DatabaseChangeListener {
    private DbChangeNotification toNotify;

    public BNSDBListener(DbChangeNotification toNotify) {
        this.toNotify = toNotify;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeEvent e) {
        synchronized( toNotify ) {
            try {
                toNotify.notifyDBChangeEvent(e); //do sth
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Util.logMessage(CLASSNAME, "onDatabaseChangeNotification", 
                    "Errors on the notifying object.", true);
                Util.printStackTrace(ex);
                Util.systemExit();                                       
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
You can use the following class to register: `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper`

```
public class oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper implements oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection {...}
```

Say you create a method somewhere:

```
public void registerPushNotification(String sql) {
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection oracleConnection = ...;//connect to db

    dbProperties.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS, "true");
    dbProperties.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION, "true");

    //this is what does the actual registering on the db end
    oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeRegistration dbChangeRegistration= oracleConnection.registerDatabaseChangeNotification(dbProperties);

    //now you can add the listener created before my EDIT
    listener = new DBListener(this);
    dbChangeRegistration.addListener(listener);

    //now you need to add whatever tables you want to monitor
    Statement stmt = oracleConnection.createStatement();
    //associate the statement with the registration:
    ((OracleStatement) stmt).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(dbChangeRegistration); //look up the documentation to this method [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleStatement.html#setDatabaseChangeRegistration_oracle_jdbc_dcn_DatabaseChangeRegistration_]

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); //you have to execute the query to link it to the statement for it to be monitored
    while (rs.next()) { ...do sth with the results if interested... }

    //see what tables are being monitored
    String[] tableNames = dbChangeRegistration.getTables();
    for (int i = 0; i < tableNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(tableNames[i]    + " has been registered.");
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
}
```

This example does not include try-catch clauses or any exception handling.

Comment: Would be interesting to see how such a listener is registered!

Comment: I am interested in learning more about this. Is  this a j2se type application or  does this  run within oracle as an oracle stored procedure?

Comment: Do you have a solution for MySQl?  Oracle is not an option for us as it is too expensive.

Comment: @All - Does this approach also works for Postgres DB ?

Comment: @All I am using oracle database and spring boot application, The spring boot app should know if something get updated  in a particular table in oracle. Can I achieve this??

Answer (score 30):

A similar Answer here: [How to make a database listener with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594955/how-to-make-a-database-listener-with-java)

You can do this with a message queue that supports transactions and just fire off a message when the transaction is comitted or (connection closed) for databases that don't support notifications. That is for the most part you will have to manually notify and keep track of what to notify.

Spring provides some auto transaction support for **AMQP** and **JMS**. A simpler alternative you could use is [Guava's AsyncEventBus](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/AsyncEventBus.html) but that will only work for one JVM.
For all of the options below I recommend you notify the rest of your  platform with a message queue.

### Option - Non-polling non-database specific

**ORM Option**

Some libraries like **Hibernate JPA** [have entity listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) that make this easier but thats because they assume that they manage all of the CRUDing.

For regular **JDBC** you'll have to do your own book keeping. That is after the connection is committed or closed you then send the message to MQ that something has been updated.

**JDBC Parsing**

One complicated option for book keeping is to wrap/decorate your `java.sql.DataSource` and/or `java.sql.Connection` in a custom one such that on [`commit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit()) (and close) you then send a message. I believe some federated caching systems do this. You could trap the executed SQL and parse to see if its an INSERT or UPDATE but with out very complicated parsing and meta data you will not get row level listening. Sadly I have to admit this is one of the advantages an **ORM** provides in that it knows what your updating.

**Dao Option**

The best option if your *not* using an ORM is to just manually send a message in your DAO after the transaction is closed that a row has been updated. *Just make sure the transaction is closed before you send the message.*

### Option - Polling non-database specific

Somewhat follow @GlenBest recommendation.

I couple of things that I would do differently. I would externalize the timer or make it so that only one server runs the timer (ie scheduler). I would just use `ScheduledExecutorService` (preferable wrapping it in Guava's `ListenerScheduledExecutorService`) instead of Quartz (IMHO using quartz for polling super overkill).

Far all of your tables you want to watch you should add a "notified" column.

Then you do something like:

```
// BEGIN Transaction
List<String> ids = execute("SELECT id FROM table where notified = 'f'");
//If db not transactional either insert ids in a tmp table or use IN clause
execute("update table set notified = 't' where notified = 'f'")
// COMMIT Transaction
for (String id : ids) { mq.sendMessage(table, id); }
```

### Option - db specific

With Postgres `NOTIFY` you'll still need to poll to some extent so you'll be doing most of the above and then send the message to the bus.

Comment: As far as the message queue is concerned, that sounds quite general - i.e. the message is just "hey I have a committed transaction"... Can you supply an exmple of how to do this in a more fine-grained way?

Comment: @LukasEder I have had this problem myself... I have not found an easy not database specific way to do it. I just added the answer because I still think its better than polling the database. But maybe that is not true. However even if you were polling a MQ would be the best option to notify all your systems that a row was updated.

Comment: Nice elaboration. After all, one can say that it really isn't simple. Just think of SQL MERGE statements. It's utterly impossible to predict what it will actually do outside of the database. So I guess the only really reliable way is, after all, some sort of polling in the database...

Comment: The DB specific part for Postgres is described at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39446972/873282

Comment: @All - Does this approach also works for Postgres DB ?

Answer (score 24):

A general solution would probably consist in creating a trigger on the table of interest, notifying any listeners about `INSERT` events. Some databases have formalised means for such inter-process notification. For instance:

#### Oracle:

- The [`DBMS_ALERT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_alert.htm) is a simple means for such notification
- [Oracle AQ / Oracle Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/information-management/streams-fov-11g-134280.pdf) provide more sophisticated queue mechanisms

#### Postgres:

- The [`NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-notify.html) statement is a simple means for such notification

#### Others:

- There might be similar notification mechanisms in other databases, that I'm not aware of.
- You can always implement your own event notification queue tables by inserting an event in an event table, which is consumed / polled by a Java process. Getting this right and performant may be quite tricky, though.

Answer (score 10):

Assumptions:

- Having standard portable code is more important than instant realtime execution of the java program.  You want to allow portability to alternative future technology (e.g. avoid proprietary DB events, external triggers).  Java process can run slightly after record is added to table (e.g. 10 seconds later). i.e. Either schedule + polling or realtime trigger/message/event are both acceptable.
- If multiple rows are added to the table all at once, you want to run one process, not many. A DB trigger would start a java process for each row - inappropriate.
- Quality of Service is important.  Even if there is a hardware or software fatal error, you want the java program to run again and process the incomplete data.
- You want to apply strong security standards to your environment (e.g. avoid having java or DB execute OS commands directly)
- You want to minimise code

  1. Core Java Standard Code without dependency on proprietary DB functionality:

     - Use ScheduledExecutorService or Quartz scheduler (or unix cron job or windows task scheduler) to run a java program every minute (or could do every 10 seconds).  This acts as both a scheduler and watchdog, ensuring program runs around the clock. Quartz can also be deployed in app server.
     - Have your java program run for just 1 minute (or 10 seconds), looping, querying DB via JDBC and sleeping for a few seconds, then finally exiting.
  2. If you have app in an appserver:
     Create a Session Bean that uses the Timer Service and again query the table via JDBC [Session Bean Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).
  3. Have a DB trigger that writes/appends to a file.  Use java 7 filewatcher to trigger logic whent the file changes [Java 7 File Watcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

There is another option: using an open source ESB with a DB adaptor triggering logic (e.g. Fuse or Mule or OpenAdapter), but this gives powerful functionality beyond your stated requirements, and is time-consuming and complex to install and learn.

EJB Timer Example using @Schedule:

```
public class ABCRequest {
   // normal java bean with data from DB
}

@Singleton
public class ABCProcessor {    
    @Resource DataSource myDataSource;   
    @EJB ABCProcessor abcProcessor;
    // runs every 3 minutes 
    @Schedule(minute="*/3", hour="*")
    public void processNewDBData() {
        // run a JDBC prepared statement to see if any new data in table, put data into RequestData
        try
        {
           Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
           PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ABC_FEED;");
           ...
           ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
           ABCRequest abcRequest
           while (rs.hasNext()) {
               // population abcRequest
           }
           abcProcessor.processABCRequest(abcRequst);
        } ...
    }    
}

@Stateless
public class class ABCProcessor {
    public void processABCRequest(ABCRequest abcRequest) {
    // processing job logic
    }
}
```

See Also: [See This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060337/remote-polling-in-managedbean-and-notify-client-view-via-push) for sending CDI Event Objects from EJB to Web container.

Comment: +1: This is also a very nice answer, specifically because of the listing of assumed requirements up front

Comment: How is this schedule different from using Quartz scheduler?

Comment: They basically do the same thing. Quartz will work in a JSE environment (basic JVM), but is not standard (can't port to another environment without Quartz).  EJB scheduler/timer will work in a full JEE environment (an app server), but not an 'EJB/JEE lite' environment (JVM or servlet container with EJB lite managed beans), but it is standard (can port to any other similar environment).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how far this solution satisfy your need but can be considered as an option. If you are using oracle, then you can write a java program and compile it as an oracle function. you can call your java program from the post insert trigger.

[Java program in oracle DB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chone.htm)

Comment: Java in Oracle can be very very slow. I'd prefer using `DBMS_ALERT` or `Oracle AQ` instead, and notify a regular Java process of any changes...