# Get Notification regarding change in Database in Java Class:

Tags: java

I want that Whenever there is any change in Specific table of database, I may be notified at run time so that I may be able to take action accordingly in my Java program. Kindly guide me if there is any way to do so.

Thanks in Advance ...

Comment: You're better off with controlling (and monitoring) the changes to your db from the outside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618915/how-to-implement-a-db-listener-in-java

Comment: Yes. But that was for Oracle database while I am using MySql

Comment: I have used triggers instead.