# Websocket server detect data change in database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql-server, websocket

I create a websocket server with Java in my localhost and i create android app connect with the websocket server and i have database in another web hosting how can the websocket server detect any update in the database ?

Comment: so, the main question how the database is accessed ? in another words how do you (insert, update,delete) data from database ? do you use Java or which language ?

Comment: Nn i mean how the websocket server know if the data in the database change(updated or deleted... )  or not

Comment: Without looking at your code, we have no clue. We need to see how you change data in the database to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the fellowing links on `stack overflow` MS SQL server doesn't fire any notification that can be observed via Java applications [as here in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145190/having-mysql-or-ms-sql-server-notify-a-java-program-that-a-table-has-been-update)

so what we can do ?  **create our own listeners!**

and we have two assumptions

1. **If you make operations(insert,update...) on database via an applications**: hence you can create a `webservice` on your Java server and the application `consumes(ie:call) this web service`  when a new data is updated, and the `web service` will notify the `web-socket` instances
2. **If the database is accessed directly from the DBMS**, so **MS SQL Server** triggers can only  invoke only `CLR`as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812233/getting-events-from-a-database) so you need to create a `Timer` using `EJB` that observes the database but this will be the worst solution

I hope this to be useful (: