# How to listen if a field (column) value is changed in sql server with Java

Tags: java

I want to get a field value in db after that field is changed. I will use Java to do it. But i don't know how I can listen if that field is changed. How can I catch it with java?

When system notices that a field is updated, my db is MSSQL server. Oracle solution won't work on it I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a db listener in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618915/how-to-implement-a-db-listener-in-java)

Comment: Its for oracle ,i need for mssql, i guess its different? i just need when a field is updated. Then i will send a e-mai as a notification