# Oracle polling from Java

Tags: java, spring, oracle, polling

I am writing a Spring application where I need to trigger an external job and wait till the job finishes (which updates a field in an Oracle table) - I am thinking of polling the table till its updated. Could anyone suggest a method of doing that in Java?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you hook it with oracle trigger?

Comment: What does *"trigger an external job"* mean?

Comment: @Andreas its a call to a Java EE servlet - e.g. http://example.com/app/JobServlet?Action=START&BatchId=123

Answer (score 1):

**Shell script**

Create a shell script, run for external job in a separate thread,let it return a proper exit code, based on the exit code received from shell, execute your dependent process

**Messaging**

Let the external job to notify once it's done, on receiving the trigger/event you can start the other process waiting for this to be done.

Comment: I don't have control on the external job.

Comment: Does the external job return any exit code? how do you invoke it?

Comment: It doesn't - its called via a url - the only way to know is when the db field is updated.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618915/how-to-implement-a-db-listener-in-java

Comment: thanks but I don't want a listener -  I want to pause and poll and proceed only once the field has been updated