# Oracle database polling with MyBatis and Spring

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, polling, spring-mybatis

need to monitor the column of a sql table if its value gets updated,this change needs to be captured in java program, based on the value, a method need to be executed like WatcherService is used in java for monitoring directory.

above requirement is to be achieved using mybatis and spring,
Thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

I would like to implement a listener like in this question : [How to implement a db listener in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618915/how-to-implement-a-db-listener-in-java)

but using spring and mybatis, and needed a service like that of Java WatchService(which keeps monitoring directory changes).

Hope I explained the problem, please let me know if need more explanation.

Comment: hope code (pseudocode at least) is clear communication between programmers. I dont understand You

Comment: The question is very broad. What specifically does not work or you have problems with when you try to implement the solution described in the linked answer using mybatis?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you mention does not use the generic JDBC interface MyBatis & Spring use to communicate with the database. This solution makes explicit references to the **Oracle JDBC driver**.

I don't think it's possible to use the specific Oracle API using MyBatis. But you are free to use the driver as the example shows; there's no limitation on it.