# Is it possible to send a insert notification from database to Spring application?

Tags: spring, database, oracle, notifications

am currently trying to trigger an event in my spring application after detecting that a line has been inserted in a Oracle database table.Having limited knowledge on databases and PL/SQL ,am struggling to find the best approche.
Note : the insertion in that table happens inside another software which means i can't manage it inside the application that am working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle you can make use of `DatabaseChangeListener`

Something like this

```
public class DBListener implements DatabaseChangeListener {
    private DbChangeNotification toNotify;

    public BNSDBListener(DbChangeNotification toNotify) {
        this.toNotify = toNotify;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeEvent e) {
        synchronized( toNotify ) {
            try {
                toNotify.notifyDBChangeEvent(e); 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Util.logMessage(CLASSNAME, "onDatabaseChangeNotification", 
                    "Errors on the notifying object.", true);
                Util.printStackTrace(ex);
                Util.systemExit();                                       
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618915/how-to-implement-a-db-listener-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the info , i will see what suits my case