# Java Derby DB in embedded server mode Change Listener

Tags: java, database, maven, vaadin, derby

I'm developing a web application and I am using `Derby DB` in `embedded server` mode (embedded and server/client mode). The application is such that when multiple machines connect to it, they share the resources of the database, obviously.. But when one machine queries a statement to the database and changes the record, I need a way to "notify" other machines of the change in the DB so that they can update their UI respectively. I looked for a way to register a `Listener` to the database, which is going to fire on updates.

I had a look at several questions here, including:

[How to implement a db listener in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618915/how-to-implement-a-db-listener-in-java)

[How to make a database listener with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594955/how-to-make-a-database-listener-with-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I couldn't find any solution regarding `Derby DB`. I simply don't know where to start from, here.

Comment: When derby doesn't implement a listener function, then you are out of luck, unless all updates are done through your code. In that case you can notify all other instances of the update as mentioned in the first link you have in your post

Comment: You have one webapp through which all the "machines"  update the db?