# Spring @Transactional Deadlock

Tags: mysql, spring, deadlock, spring-transactions

I have the following setup.

- Spring 3.0.5
- Hibernate 3.5.6
- MySql 5.1

To save a record in the DB via Hibernate I have the following workflow

1. send JSON `{id:1,name:"test",children:[...]}` to Spring MVC App and use Jackson to transform it into an object graph (if it is an existing instance the JSON has the proper ID of the record in the DB set
2. save the object in DB via service layer call  (details below)

   - the save function of service layer interface `SomeObjectService` has the @Transactional annotation on it with `readOnly=false` and Propagation `REQUIRED`
   - the implementation of this service layer `SomeObjectServieImpl` calls the DAO save 
     method
   - the DAO saves the new data via a call of hibernate's merge e.g. `hibernateTempate().merge(someObj)`
   - hibernate `merge` loads the object first from the DB via `SELECT`
   - I have a EntityListener who is wired to spring (I used this technique [Spring + EntityManagerFactory +Hibernate Listeners + Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143881/spring-entitymanagerfactory-hibernate-listeners-injection)) and listens to `@PostLoad`
   - The listener uses a `LockingServie` to updates one field of `someObject` to set it as locked (this **should actually only happen when `someObject` is loaded via Hibernate HQL,SQL or Criteria calls** but gets called also on merge)
   - the `LockingServie` has a function `lock(someObj,userId)` which is also annotated with @Transactional with `readOnly=false` and `REQUIRED`
   - the update happens via a call of `Query query = sess.createQuery("update someObj set lockedBy=:userId");` and then
     `query.executeUpdate();`
   - after merge has loaded the data it start with updating `someObject` and inserting relevant children (<= exacely here is the point where the **deadlock happens**)
3. return JSON result (this also includes the newly created object ID) back to client.

The problem seems for me that first

1. the record gets loaded in a transaction
2. then gets changed in another (inner-)transaction
3. and then should get updated again with the data of the outer transaction but can't get updated because it is locked.

I can see via MySQL's

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES
```

that a child table (that is part of the object graph) is locked.

Interesting fact is that the **deadlock doesn't occur on the someObj** table but rather on a table that represents a child.

I am a bit lost here. Any help is more than welcome.

BTW can maybe the [isolation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#isolation()) level get me out of this problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using @Bozho's `HibernateExtendedJpaDialect`

which is explained here >> 
[Hibernate, spring, JPS & isolation - custom isolation not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234240/hibernatespringjpaisolation-does-not-work)

To set the isolation to **READ_UNCOMMITED**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public Seizure merge(Seizure seizureObj);
```

Not a very nice solution I know but at least this solved my problem.

If somebody wanna have a detailed description please ask...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution to the problem, but I would not have a transactional lock method. If at all you need to lock something manually, make it within another transactional service method.